# in SVN renamed file disappeared after revert

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

I use eclipse with tortoise SVN. What I did is,

1. renamed a file like Test1.java -> Test2.java;
2. before committing this change, I did revert.
3. after revert, I noticed the file disappeared. Whatever Test1.java or Test2.java.

I tried to bring back Test1.java by copying from repobrowser. However, the file is not showing up with revision number at all.

Comment: Was `Test1.java` committed to the repo before you renamed it, or was it a new file?

Comment: I did not commit it at all. It's one of the files of the original revision. I picked up another file, and reproduced the symptom.

Comment: Try to `Refresh` project.

Comment: Can you do a svn log on the directory and paste the latest changes so that it may be easier for us to understand what is going on.